# SSH can not execute an .exe program with GUI on WMware Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, executable

I have system like this. I have host windows 10 and a VM windows 7. I have ssh server set up on the guest VM. I can connect via windows' openSSH client to the VM. I can execute commands like `/DIR` or `echo hello > hello.txt` but when it comes to execute the .exe file it does not start. Or it starts but I dont have any output in the foreground. I am using the guest VM's windows account while I am opening ssh connection.

I have tried start command of cmd with different kinds of parameters but none of them works in my case. What is it that I am missing? How can I solve this problem? I

Comment: Which kind of EXE are you trying to launch? If it's a command-line program, you should be able to run it. But if it's a GUI tool you are out of luck, it just can't run over a text-only terminal connection.

Comment: Yes it has a gui. I actually see when I execute `tasklist` command. It is working and has a process Id. But what is also interesting is this process is not listed in the VM itself in windows task manager. Isnt there a way to open the GUI of the exe ?

Comment: Not on a terminal connection. You should use RDP.

Comment: This question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880794/starting-gui-programs-via-openssh-on-windows/65899949#65899949